# In-memory transformations on a reactive stream in Project Reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, blocking, project-reactor, in-memory

I have the following interface:

```
interface Checker {
  Mono<Foo> check(Bar bar);
}
```

Also note that `Bar` has a method `getPizzas()`:

```
class Bar {
  List<Pizza> getPizzas() { ... }
}
```

On some cases, the implementing class uses the benefit of non blocking IO operations, by using a reactive-enabled HTTP client.

However, on other cases, there are no IO operations, so that I only want to use a method `transform` that takes `List<Pizza>` and returns an instance of `Foo` and would return it as a `Mono<Foo>`.

The signature of `transform` is:

```
Foo transform(List<Pizza> pizzas) { ... }
```

From what I understand, I have two options (maybe more) to implement such Checker:

Option [1.a] - use the reactive stream approach as much as possible:

```
Mono<Foo> check(Bar bar) {
  return Flux.fromIterable(bar.getPizzas()).collectList().map(pizzas -> transform(pizzas));
}
```

Option [1.b] - almost the same as [1.a]:

```
Mono<Foo> check(Bar bar) {
  return Mono.just(bar.getPizzas()).map(pizzas -> transform(pizzas));
}
```

Option [2] - use pure Java for in-memory transformation:

```
Mono<Foo> check(Bar bar) {
  return Mono.just(transform(bar.getPizzas()));
}
```

**My questions:**

Is there a difference in the options described above?

Will using the reactive `map` be a better approach if `transform` is CPU intensive and takes a significant amount of time (say, more than 2 seconds)?

Comment: As per my understanding, all the methods do exactly the same thing. In the option 1, you are using map operator which makes a synchronous call to an expensive function. Similarly in option 2, you call the transform function to transform the object and then create a flux out of the result. All are essentially the same. You should use flatMap instead of map to perform the intensive work asynchronously.

Comment: @uneq95 `flatMap` is not asynchronous.

Comment: Option 1 allows you to defer the execution and run it asynchronously using `subscribeOn` or `publishOn` e.g.

Comment: @a better oliver seriously? A flatmap isnt asynchronous? Why does the documentation says the contrary? Flatmap: "Transform the elements emitted by this Flux asynchronously into Publishers". Can you please comment on this? How is my understanding on this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are performing a transformation on each Pizza, there is no reason to use Flux. Also, each of the methods you provided will do exactly the same thing. If you are worried about CPU intensive operations, you should subscribe to the operation using the Parallel thread-pool, to offload the work and free up the event loop thread.

```
Mono.just(bar.getPizzas())
   .map(pizzas -> transform(pizzas))
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
```